# JqueryMobile Knockout and Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout and jquerymobile and can't get it to work.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="/nw/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/nw/scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="/nw/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nw/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
        <title>title</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.test = [{ "name": "noam", "age": "36" }, { "name": "yael", "age": "34"}];
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel());
        });
</script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: test" id="myList">
    <li>test <span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this I get the following error:
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

When I comment out the jquerymobile scripts, it works.

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Have to tried changing the order of the scripts.Like moving the jquery mobile up before knockout.js.

Comment: Yes I did, it was originally there. Can you try and copy the code out and see how it works for you?

Comment: Not sure if this could be the cause, but try using $(document).bind('pageinit') instead of $(document).ready(): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the problem is the placement of the `<script>` block where `ko.applyBindings` is called. The example works as-is if you move the `<script>` block into the `<head>` tag, as follows: (also note use of `pageinit` event and `data-role="page"` attribute)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <title>title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
      this.test = [{ "name": "noam", "age": "36" }, { "name": "yael", "age": "34"}];
    }
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
      ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel());
    });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
      <ul data-bind="foreach: test" id="myList">
        <li>test <span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that both jquery mobile and knockout alter the DOM, and the DOM error is symptomatic of a clash between them, where one library has moved a DOM element that the other one has subsequently tried to address.

To get JQM and knockout to work together (which they do), you need to be quite familiar with when/how JQM makes its changes to the DOM. [This page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) might be a good starting point.